# Поднять сервер дома в денвере через роутер D-link dir400

Tags: веб-сервер, роутер, порты, denwer

Ребята, добрый вечер.Ситуация такая, есть денвер и есть роутер d-link dir 400.

На денвере есть сайт "project.ru"Сегодня взял статичный ip адрес, и теперь хочу сделать так чтобы по этому адресу можно было заходить на проект на денвере.

Все что получилось сделать, прописать в роутере в port fordwarding - новый статичный айпишник, порты 80 - 80, tcp, и теперь по этому адресу хотябы заходит на страницу моего роутера, вначале вообще никуда не вело.

А каким образом перевести теперь айпишник на проект? Уже голова кругом идет от кол-ва перечитанных мануалов...

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно добавить в DNS запись типа A с указанием вашего IP. Можно воспользоваться для начала каким-нибудь бесплатным сервисом. Например, http://freedns.ws/en/

Answer (score 1):

Как сказано авторами постов выше, надо:

1. Зарегистрировать свой домен на свой ВНЕШНИЙ статический IP
2. Добавить ВНУТРЕННИЙ IP хоста с сайтом в [DMZ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8)) ИЛИ
3. В роутере [пробросить](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) порт 80 на ВНУТРЕННИЙ IP хоста с сайтом, при условии наличия в запросе имени сайта.

Как-то так...)

Answer (score 1):

Допустим адрес твоей машинка, где денвер крутится 192.168.0.10
Тогда:

- как уже говорили, регистрируешь свой белый IP в рачестве адреса для доменного имени
- На роутере переадресуешь 80 порт на 192.168.0.10 порт 80
- в папке home  денвера создаешь папку 192.168.0.10 и копируешь туда папку www

Дополнительно хочу сказать, что денвер предназначен только для тестирования, но никак не для работы реального сайта. В документации денвера это КАПСОМ НАПИСАНО

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить свой локальный хост в DMZ в роутере. Там все порты должны быть открыты напрямую внешним запросам.

Answer (score 0):

Проброс портов ТАК не делается! Если у роутера порт для управления - 80, то проброс надо делать 80 (внутренний) - 8080 (внешний). То есть, в роутере переадресовывать всё, что поступает с внешнего 8080 на внутренний IP, порт 80. Можно и наоборот, если для управления роутером в нём выбрать порт, например 8080. Тогда 80-й внешний может быть отображён на 80-й внутренний, а управление роутером - по 8080. Надеюсь, не очень путано объяснил?

Тут нужно понимать, что проброс портов - это способ достичь внутренних ресурсов ЗА роутером. Поэтому в роутере определённый порт привязывается к определённому внутреннему ресурсу. Соответствие портов и ресурсов - и есть проброс портов.