# Доступ к серверу из интернета

Tags: ubuntu, роутер, faq

На моем компьютере стоит ubuntu 14 с LAMP сервером, комп выходит в интернет через роутер при подключении WiFi, у меня есть еще и второй комп с виндой, он также выходит в интернет через тот самый роутер, но уже подключен к роутеру через шнурок. Когда я на втором компе обращаюсь к своему серверу, все работает, ftp, ssh и phpmyadmin, в общем, все гут.

Вот теперь хочу, чтобы к моему серверу можно было подключиться из интернета.

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Если есть хороший мануал буду очень благодарен за ссылочку на него.

Comment: вопрос не имеет (прямого) отношения к вашим компьютерам, а имеет прямое отношение к вашему интернет-провайдеру и вашему роутеру.

Comment: начните с телефонного звонка вашему интернет-провайдеру с вопросом: «сколько будет стоить выделение вам внешнего ip-адреса?»

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я так понял надо делать проброс портов в роутере

Comment: да, надо делать т.н. проброс портов. запрошенный вами «мануал» называется «инструкция по эксплуатации вашего роутера». ищите её в коробке из-под роутера или на сайте производителя.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. нужен внешний ip-адрес (ipv4, разумеется), который может предоставить вам ваш интернет-провайдер. бесплатно или за деньги.
2. нужно настроить ваш маршрутизатор, чтобы он внешние обращения на нужные вам порты (или вообще все внешние обращения) переадресовывал на тот из ваших компьютеров, который будет эти обращения обрабатывать. смотрите инструкцию по эксплуатации вашего маршрутизатора.
3. как правило, никаких изменений в конфигурации компьютеров не требуется.

---

другие вопросы на ru.so со схожей тематикой:

- [Как прокинуть IP-адрес через роутер?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/340485)
- [Доступ к серверу по внешнему IP через роутер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/346929)
- [Настройка доступа к сайту извне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/415288)
- [Поднять сервер дома в денвере через роутер D-link dir400](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/344662)
- [Настройка роутера TrendNet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/423477)
- [Проброс портов на роутере TP-Link 940N](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495828)
- [Как настроить доступ к web-серверу в локальной сети?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431591)
- [Как присвоить ститичный ip адрес компьютеру в wifi?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/348685)
- [Настройка сервера на домашнем ПК](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/559905)
- [Как узнать к какому компьютеру подключится клиент?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/756773)
- [Доступ из интернета к сайту на домашнем компьютере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/757775)
- [Подключение к веб-серверу из глобальной сети](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/934404)