# Как задать внешний ip адрес гостевой системе kvm

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Здравствуйте. Решил научиться поднимать vps. Раньше ни разу такого не делал. Начал искать в интернете информацию о том как это делается, ничего абсолютно не понятно. Установил kvm, bridge-utils, virt-manager. Прописал конфиги /etc/network/interfaces - ничего. Адрес в локальной сети имеется. Внутри нее пингуется, внешний ip ни в какую не получается задать. В общем в голове каша, извините, если где-то чушь сморозил. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как это делается. Основная система ubuntu server 14.04. Гостевая такая же.

Под внешним ip подразумеваю адрес по которому к виртуальной машине можно будет подключиться из интернета.

Comment: так как «адрес в локальной сети имеется», то ответ на этот, например, вопрос, вам вполне подойдёт: [Доступ к серверу из интернета](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523111/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ссылку.