# Связь двух машин через интернет с помощью WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Недавно начал изучать WCF. Написал простейшую прилогу. Клиент отправляет строку, сервер принимает и выводит на экран. Всё прекрасно работает на моем компе при локальном адресе. А когда пытаюсь связаться через веб - выпадает исключение:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://(IP):4000/IContract that could accept the message.

Порты открыты и доступны. Подскажите, может, я чего упускаю? Вот так выглядит адрес:
`Uri adress = new Uri("http://(Тут_IP_компа,_на_котором_сервер):4000/IContract");`
Свой IP взял с этого сайта: https://2ip.com.ua/ua Уже не знаю, что делать, если честно. Буду благодарен любой подсказке.

Comment: а порты открыты? А ip статический?

Comment: конфиг сервиса настроен на работу с внешним IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заказал статический IP, и подсоединился к Ethernet напрямую, без роутера. Заработало. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

> Свой IP взял с этого сайта: https://2ip.com.ua/ua

вы получили адрес [шлюза](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7), через который ваш компьютер «общается» с интернетом.

соответственно, ваша программа обращается к шлюзу, а не к вашему компьютеру. со вполне очевидным результатом.

---

надеюсь, вам поможет информация из ответа на этот вопрос: [Доступ к серверу из интернета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523111/178576)