# Настройка сервера на домашнем ПК

Tags: node.js, ip, веб-сервер

Привет. Я бы хотел разобраться с одной очень волнующей меня проблемой. 
Я написал простой node.js скрипт:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(req, res){

res.end("server is running!");

}).listen(8080);
```

Что ж, сервер принимает запросы на порту 8080 и с локального адреса в браузере все отображается так, как нужно. Но что если я хочу, чтобы мой друг подсоединился к этому простенькому серверу? Я определил свой сетевой айпи, не локальный, но при подключении к нему никакого ответа не следует, я вбиваю 192.168.0.105:8080 и все работает у меня, но не у друзей, потом вбиваю 141.138.104.72:8080 (сетевой адрес), но не работает ни у меня, ни у друзей. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно ещё сделать для того, чтобы люди могли подключаться к этому небольшому серверу? Что упущено?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых: Является ли определенный Вами IP адрес статическим? Если нет - при следующем переподключении к Интернет адрес будет недействительный
Во-вторых: `192.168.0.105:8080` - адрес в локальной сети. Для того чтобы получить доступ к компьютеру по этому адресу извне, необходимо настроить прокидывание портов на Вашем роутере (если он есть), настроить файрвол (открыть необходимый порт) опять же, если он есть.
Здесь может быть еще одна проблема - провайдер может закрывать подобные порты. В таком случае может помочь проксирование.
Если честно, это дело не самое простое для человека, не разбирающегося в сетях вообще. Я бы начал с настройки маршрутизатора (при его наличии) и проверки доступности порта.
P.S. Если роутер все-таки есть, решить проблему динамического IP позволяют сервисы Dynamic DNS. В настройках роутера можно поискать поддерживаемые сервисы и зарегистрировать имя.

Comment: Вы правы. В настройках TP-LINK говорится, что динамический. Мне в настройках копаться? А что значит прокидывание портов? Надо, чтобы маршрутизатор перенаправлял запросы по указанному в коде порту мне на компьютер?

Comment: @Muller У TP_LINK это называется `Виртуальные серверы`, на сколько помню. Там можно указать входящий порт извне (например 80), IP адрес внутри локальной сети (в Вашем случае 192.168.0.105) и внутренний порт (8080). Таким образом, запросы на роутер будут переправляться с 80 порта (стандартный HTTP) на 8080 порт Вашего компьютера. DDNS у TP_LINK тоже есть. У меня, по крайней мере, такая система работает отлично.

Comment: Превосходно. Премного Вам благодарен. То есть, мне только создать вирт. сервер и зарегистрировать DDNS у одного из провайдеров? И все?

Comment: @Muller в общем то да, для начала этого будет достаточно

Comment: Ещё раз огромное спасибо

Comment: @Muller удачи в программировании

Comment: и Вам больших успехов