# доступ к vmware извне

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, vmware, nat

есть win 7, на ней стоит vmware с убунтой 12.04.5

нужно сделать так, чтобы к виртуальной оси был доступ извне

сижу за роутером на tp-link-741ND с прошивкой dd-wrt, на нем включил режим dmz

хотелось бы уточнить, какие настройки вбивать в /etc/network/interfaces и в сам vmware

Comment: 1. [половина ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523182/178576) 2. ещё четверть ответа: `/etc/network/interfaces` изменять нет необходимости. 3. остаётся четверть про конфигурацию vmware. подозреваю, что настройки по умолчанию вполне подойдут, а если нет, то затрудняюсь подсказать, как в терминологии, используемой разработчиками vmware может называться *сетевой мост* (*network bridge*).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, благодарю, все сделал