# Проблема с настройкой сети: не могу сделать ping самого себя

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, ip

Доброго времени суток.
Пишу свое приложение Server и Client. Есть проблема с подключением к Server. А именно при connect в Client происходит ошибка: сеть не доступна.
При попытке сделать ping своего внешнего IP адреса происходит ошибка: сеть недоступна.
Как решить эту проблему?

Upd:
Прилагаю вывод команды ip a, ip r, свой внешний ip

```
IP : 176.100.250.16
```

[image: ip r]

[image: ip a]

Comment: а ping проходит?

Comment: нет. тоже пишет, что сеть недоступна

Comment: исправьте вопрос. у вас проблемы с настройкой сети, а не с python. добавьте информацию про ping. уберите все про python.

Comment: приложите к вопросу вывод команды `$ ip a; ip r` а также ip-адрес, который вы считаете «своим внешним».

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют

Answer (score 2):

ваш «внешний» ip-адрес присутствует в приведённой вами информации: `10.104.4.156`.

ваш «внутрениий» ip-адрес даже не нужно нигде «подсматривать». это `127.0.0.1`.

если написанный вами «сервер» сконфигурирован прослушивать подключения на всех интерфейсах, то написанный вами «клиент», будучи запущенным на этой же машине, может подключаться к любому из этих двух адресов.

---

а тот адрес, который вы считаете «внешним», к вашему компьютеру, скорее всего, не имеет никакого отношения. это один из множества ip-адресов, используемых вашим интернет-провайдером. если этот адрес (согласно договору) закреплён за вами, то он должен ретранслироваться (провайдером) на ваше оборудование, подключенное непосредственно к сети провайдера. вероятно, это какой-нибудь маршрутизатор. и чтобы по этому адресу можно было «достучаться» до вашей машины, потребуется некоторая настройка вашего маршрутизатора. посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523182/178576) (и ссылки в нём).