# Доступ извне к KSWEB

Tags: android, nginx, mobile

Возможно ли настроить KSWEB для доступа из глобальной сети? Использую Nginx, доступ по локальной сети есть. Отображает так же и глобальный IP, но к нему нет доступа извне.[image]

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523111/178576

Comment: Разве телефон нужно настраивать как роутер и пробрасывать в телефоне порты? И ещё - достаточно иметь любой IP, не обязательно статический. Меня другой момент смущает, может дело на стороне провайдера? Использую YOTA.