# Как узнать к какому компьютеру подключится клиент?

Tags: linux, сеть, ip

Долго думал как назвать вопрос. Есть 2 компьютера один с Win10x64 другой с Ubuntu Server оба подключены к одному модему, собираюсь оформить услугу выделенный IP что бы сделать сервер например CS ну и в дальнейшем поставить на этот сервер сайт. Так вот вопрос в том если будет один IP на модем то как клиенты будут знать к какому именно компу подключатся заходя по IP к win10 или к Ubuntu Server?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523182/178576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от того, на какую машину будут проброшены порты из модема. Можно сразу на обе машины. Внешне это будет выглядеть как адрес модема и только он, а дальше запрос пойдет в зависимости от настроек самого модема.