# Доступ из интернета к сайту на домашнем компьютере

Tags: веб-сервер, hosting

Есть сайт, который развёрнут на домашнем компьютере, необходимо чтобы он был доступен из интернета.

Ubuntu 16.04 server, Nginx, ASP.Net Core. Потребуется инсталяция/настройка Nginx и Ubuntu, это понятно.

Какие настройки необходимо сделать в операционке и в модеме?

Answer (score 1):

1) Сделать проброс портов, а именно 80 порт сделать доступным.

2) Иметь прямой (белый) IP-адрес (к провайдеру)

3) Если под модемом имеется ввиду USB-модем у которого как таковых настроек нету, то в случае если провайдер предоставляет белый IP думаю достаточно в брандмауэре открыть порты.

Comment: Под модемом подразумевается Wifi роутер. Спасибо !

Comment: Иметь белый IP не обязательно, если у провайдера можно подключить услугу переадресации или туннеля.