# Настройка домен в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, домен

Есть домен, и домашний сервер на Ubuntu. На нем ftp, и http сайт, и ssh. Куда прописать dns и если надо другое чтобы вместо ip для ftp/сайта/ssh надо было вводить домен?

Comment: Где регистрировали домен, там и прописывайте

Comment: Нужно чтобы это работало из интернета? Тогда вот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757775/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5 а затем на делегированном DNS в тип "А" записи вписать IPv4 ваш белый IP. Если нужен IPv6 - то использовать запись "AAAA".

Comment: Спасибо, а изменять DNS на сервере не надо?

Comment: Вы зарегали домен. Обычно сразу при регистрации предлагают указать записи ns - в них прописывается DNS сервера. Посмотреть можно так: `dig ns stackoverflow.com +short` - обратите внимание, только для домена второго уровня! Также я добавил `+short` чтобы вам было проще. Попробуйте и без этого параметра. Вы получите список DNS серверов. Вот на них и надо настраивать все DNS записи. На своей домашней убунте в вашем случае, DNS-сервера, я уверен, что нет, да и не нужен он. Разберитесь как работает DNS, если будут вопросы, пишите

Comment: Купил домен, в настройках сделал A запись как вы сказали, при попытки зайти на сайт DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. \

Comment: Добавил dns серверы в netplan, вот что выходит при запуске Error in network definition //etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml line 11 column 25: malformed address 'ns71.domaincontrol.com', must be X.X.X.X or X:X:X:X:X:X:X:X