# Создание Майнкрафт сервера в Linux - как разрешить порт 25565?

Tags: linux, port

Всем привет, схема такая:

Android смартфон > Wi-Fi > Ноутбук на Linux > Интернет > другой Android смартфон

Все сделал, как по инструкциям, сервер запускается, но к нему невозможно подключиться (долгий коннект, затем TimeoutException. Грешу на порт 25565. Как его открыть в Linux?

В качестве адресa сервера использую androidip:25565. Так как сервер установлен на ноутбуке, которому через Android раздается Wi-Fi

Пробовал, так:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 25565 --syn -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables-savе
```

Не помогло

Comment: Используйте iptables

Comment: *Как его открыть в Linux?* -- точно так же, как и в любой другой ОС, не?

Comment: @Insider, конечно же iptables, но он не помог, обновил вопрос

Comment: Интернет на ноутбуке, скорей всего под `NAT` и скорей всего, ваш сервер в инете видно не будет, не получится пробросить. Если только `NOIP` юзать или `DDNS`, мож еще что есть. Либо переделывать подключение к интернету. А порт, сервер, открывает сам. Его не нужно самому открывать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523111/178576

Comment: @And, тоесть, если ноутбук подключен к Wifi на нем нельзя запустить сервер? и никак нельзя прокинуть порт? андроид рутованный

Comment: как и сказал @And скорее всего у вас NAT или Динамический NAT. Либо делайте статический айпи, либо же используйте разные NOIP сервисы.

Comment: Маршруты у вас сделать не получится, так как вы, больше чем уверен, под `NAT`. Какой есть выход? 1. Переделывать подключение интернета, чтобы все проходило в ручную. 2.Сделать выделенный ип от провайдера (но тут не всем дают, уже нужно уточнять у вашего провайдера). 3. Поднимать виртуалку. 4. Скачать программу `Tunngle` и взять ип для сервера, - все кто зайдет в программу, смогут зайти к вам на сервер.