# Подключение к веб-серверу из глобальной сети

Tags: c++, http, сеть, веб-сервер, tcp-ip

Я пишу свой веб-сервер на C++. Планируется подключаться к нему с браузера, а он в ответ должен выдавать html-странички. Так вот вопрос, при подключении к нему с устройств локальной сети(дома wi-fi роутер) по локальному IP с указанием порта - всё хорошо. Но как подключиться к серверу из глобальной сети? Просто указание глобального IP с портом не работает. Проброс порта 8080 сделал.

Comment: нужен белый внешний IP

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к серверу из интернета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523111/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

Дайте угадаю. 
Проверяете "глобальный IP" из той же сети, за NAT'ом?
Для того чтобы это сработало, ваш роутер должен быть соответствующим образом настроен.

Если я угадал - попробуйте сделать http-запрос из другой сети, например, через мобильную сеть.

В противном случае, вероятно, что-то вы не так настроили. Предлагаю показать конфигурацию.