# API на локальной машине для внешних пользоватлей

Tags: api, flask

Есть необходимость запускать программу на локальной машине удаленно. Хотел поднять api на flask для этого. Вопрос, как стучаться на это api c внешних устройств?

Comment: судя по содержимому ответа, это [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523111/178576)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к серверу из интернета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523111/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно подключить статический IP адрес у провайдера и пробросить наружу соответствующие порты.

Правда, самое лучшее решение для подобных задач арендовать сервер в облаке.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Провайдер ответил "выдается белый IP адрес динамически, но всегда один и тот же". Я так понял, что с этим можно реализовать данную схему?

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не участвовал и не могу участвовать в Вашем диалоге с провайдером. Здесь главное, чтобы IP был постоянно один и тот же. Иначе замучаетесь менять IP  в настройках внешнего софта.