# nginx не находит сервер сайта

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, virtualbox

решил попробовать сделать небольшую статическую хтмл страничку на nginx.Собственно после написания хтмл и всех конфигов решил проверить работу.На локалхосте,127.0.0.1 и 0.0.0.0 страничка правильно открывалась. Но по своему доменному имени и по IP(получил через `curl -4 icanhazip.com`) она недоступна(вылетают таймауты).
Однако если вручную прописать в etc/hosts привязку домена к этому IP и использовать команду
 `sudo ifconfig enp0s3 109.252.1.28`
(enp0s3-мой роутер ,видимо)все криво ,но работает.С других устройств все равно не выходит зайти.Как  решать проблему? Да и вообще ,где происходит привязка моего IP к nginx? Совсем новичок ,так что если возможно,то ответьте подробнее,буду очень благодарен.

**site1.conf**

```
server {  
    listen 80 ;

    root /var/www/html/site1;

    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name     www.oleghelp1.com       oleghelp1.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: А ваш роутер настроен на то, чтобы входящие из других устройств запросы перенаправлять в ваш компьютер?

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаю. Как можно проверить?

Comment: Изучайте основы компьютерных сетей. NAT, перенаправление портов, межсетевой экран, вот это вот всё

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к серверу из интернета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523111/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)