# Как открыть локальный сервер для доступа извне?

Tags: сервер, ssh, localhost

Недавно настроил ubuntu server на китайской тв приставке. Подключился к ней с помощью Termius через SSH, все прекрасно. Однако я могу подключиться к ней только в пределах локальной сети, при попытке зайти через мобильные данные, Termius конечно же ничего не находит. Какие есть варианты, чтобы "открыть" сервер миру. Слышал о каком-то методе с перенаправлением портов, но адекватной инструкции так и не нашел. Какие есть варианты ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к серверу из интернета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523111/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: Видимо NAT мешает, потом нужен либо постоянный IP адрес, либо DDNS

Comment: Коороче гуглите "How to setup a linux server behind NAT" с указанием модели вашего роутера