# Как прикрутить домен к локальному сайту (ubuntu 18)

Tags: apache, dns

Как прикрутить домен к локальному сайту на Apache2 (ubuntu 18)?

Comment: Также как и к любому другому сайту. Просто укажите ваш статический белый IP в DNS редакторе домена.

Comment: нашел. но если в ns2 введу не верный ип а в ns1 верный, срабоатет? У меня нет 2 ип.

Comment: а вообше мне нужно чтобы саит был даступен в инете. Мне нужно обрашение от сторонего сайта словити по определенному адресу

Comment: Причём тут ns1/ns2 ?? Это адреса NS-серверов. Вам их должен предоставить регистратор. А вам надо создать A-запись в зоне.

Comment: регистратор предоставляет, но я думал нужно свои сделати

Comment: вот ято я сделал https://kifarunix.com/configure-bind-as-dns-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: systemd-resolve --status DNS Servers и DNS Domain выдает один и тот же ip, И если это и работает то что дальше.

Comment: ещё один [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523111/178576)

Comment: @Mr.X , забудьте про DNS на сервере, он вам не нужен. Всё что нужно сделать - я уже написал.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете в виду перенаправление на localhost с указанного доменного имени, вам следует прописать в /etc/hosts строку:

```
127.0.0.1      ВАШ.ДОМЕН
```

Comment: нет. чтобы открывался как обычный. Наверне с DNS bind9