# Подключится по ssh через роутер

Tags: linux, сеть, ssh

Значится так: я хотел бы подключаться по ssh к своему домашнему компу на fedora 32 через терминал с удаленного устройства.
Но у меня дома сеть, а значит стоит роутер, который эту сеть организует.
Если бы мой комп был подключен напрямую без роутера, то можно было бы просто

```
ssh <user>@<ip>
```

Но так как есть роутер то команда выше не приведет к желанному результату.
Мне нужно каким то образом подключатся к своему компу через роутер.
У меня роутер кенетик лайт и в нем есть терминальный интерфейс и можно к этому роутеру подключится через ssh и даже попасть в ос роутера. Но дальше я пройти не могу ибо в этой терминальной ос роутера нет команды ssh.
Получается что я не могу сделать

```
ssh <admin>@<white_ip>
```

Это приведет меня в роутер. А здесь уже.

```
ssh <user>@<local_ip>
```

Это привело бы меня в локально подключенное к роутеру устройство.
А как же мне подключится к домашнему компу через роутер? Чтобы я мог с другого какого то места попасть в терминал своего домашнего компа.

Comment: Пробросить порт на нужный компьютер

Comment: @вот здесь у меня возникает проблема. Давайте представим что я никогда не пробрасывал порты и не совсем понимаю как это делать чтобы выполнить условие из вопроса(подключится к компу через роутер). Можете ли вы помочь с инструкцией как это делается?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523182/398802

Comment: читайте инструкцию к вашему роутеру.

Comment: Если кратко; на роутере сделать проброс при внешнем обращении на порт 2223(пример) перенаправляя его на ip 192.168.1.123 22(пример ip и port ssh пк). Далее подключаться с внешнего устройства `ssh -p2223 <user>@<white_ip>`

Answer (score 1):

Роутер висит на "сером" адресе, следовательно, надо сделать его доступным извне. Это делается двумя способами:

1. покупкой "белого" (внешнего персонального) адреса;
2. либо DDNS. Например, Zyxel предоставляет пользователям своих роутеров получить адрес такого типа: имя_для_трансляции.имя_роутера.keenetic.* через который можно организовать проброс. Например, так имя_для_трансляции.имя_роутера.keenetic.*:8443 <> "серый_адрес_роутера":8443 <> "мой_комп":22
   [Описание на сайте ZyXel](https://help.keenetic.com/hc/ru/articles/360000400919)