# Проблема при настройке удаленного доступа по ssh к гостевой Ubuntu Server на облаке

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, ssh, vmware, облако

Задача: получить доступ к установленной в облаке гостевой ОС - Ubuntu Server.
На данный момент удалось настроить NAT для доступа к интернету из гостевой ОС.
Для доступа ssh были введены следующие настройки(последняя строка на картинке).
ssh на сервере установлен и запущен, служба активна. Порт 22.
Внешний ip  с другого компьютера пингуется, но по ssh подключиться не получается (через putty).
В чем может быть проблема? В настройках сети или в настройках ssh в гостевой ОС?

локальный ip гостевой ос 192.168.5.55
Настройки NAT в облаке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доступ в интернет на гостевой ОС работает. Настроить ssh не удается.

Comment: изложите, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса (нажав [edit]), что именно вы подразумеваете под «настройкой ssh» вообще, и что именно у вас не получается в частности.

Comment: в общем и целом — [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523111/178576).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Стат. ip адрес имеется, здесь скорее мои ошибки в настройках сети, не могу понять в какую сторону копать.

Comment: 1. читайте документацию этого вашего неназванного «облака». 2. обращайтесь в техподдержку того же самого неназванного «облака».