# как сделать сервер на uWebSockets доступным из сети?

Tags: c++, websocket

всем привет, мне нужно написать сервер, который принимает команды от клиентов и делает что-то с базой данных. по SQL у меня нет вопросов, но выбирая способ связи с клиентами, наткнулся на uWebSockets и вот с такого кода, у меня все работает, но это работает только на локалхост. не могу найти как сделать, чтоб сервер был общедоступный в сети по статическому ip:port?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <uwebsockets/App.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
struct UserConnection {
    std::string name;
    unsigned long user_id;
};
/*
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/");
ws.onmessage=({data})=>console.log(data);
ws.send("somecommand");
*/
void newUserConnected(std::string channel, auto * ws, std::string name, unsigned int user_id) {
    std::string_view message("NEW_USER=" + std::to_string(user_id) + "," + name);
    ws->publish("broadcast", message);
}
int main()
{
    int port = 8888;
    unsigned long latest_user_id = 10;
    std::map<unsigned long, std::string> online_users;
   

    uWS::App().ws<UserConnection>("/*", {
        .open = [&latest_user_id, &online_users](auto* ws) {
            UserConnection* data = (UserConnection*)ws->getUserData();
            data->user_id = latest_user_id++;
            data->name = "UNNAMED";
            std::cout << "New user connected ID = " << data->user_id << std::endl;
            ws->subscribe("broadcast");
            std::string user_channel("user#" + std::to_string(data->user_id));
            ws->subscribe(user_channel);
            //connection open
            online_users[data->user_id] = data->name;
            for (auto entry : online_users) {
                newUserConnected(user_channel, ws, entry.second, entry.first);
            }
           
        },
        .message = [&online_users](auto* ws, std::string_view message, uWS::OpCode opCode) {
            std::string SET_NAME("SET_NAME=");
            std::string MESSAGE_TO("MESSAGE_TO=");


            UserConnection* data = (UserConnection*)ws->getUserData();
            std::cout << "New message received = " << message << std::endl;
            if (message.find(SET_NAME) == 0) {
                std::cout << "User sets their name" << std::endl;
                data->name = message.substr(SET_NAME.length());
                online_users[data->user_id] = data->name;
                newUserConnected("broadcast",ws, data->name, data->user_id);
            }
            if (message.find("MESSAGE_TO") == 0) {
                std::cout << "User sends private message" << std::endl;
                auto rest = std::string(message.substr(MESSAGE_TO.length()));
                int comma_position = rest.find(",");
                auto ID = rest.substr(0, comma_position);
                auto text = data->name + ": " + rest.substr(comma_position + 1);

                ws->publish("user#" + std::string(ID), text);
            }

        },
        .close = [&online_users](auto* ws, int code, std::string_view message)
        {
            UserConnection* data = (UserConnection*)ws->getUserData();
            ws->publish("broadcast", "DISCONNECT=" + data->user_id);
            online_users.erase(data->user_id);
        },
        }).listen(port, [&port](auto* token) {
            if (token)
              std::cout << "Server started successfully on port " << port << std::endl;
            else std::cout<< "Server failed to start" << std::endl;
        }).run();
}
```

Comment: Очевидно, что для начала надо раздобыть статический IP у своего интернет провайдера.

Comment: а по делу ответить можно? у меня вопрос к коду, а не к организации статического IP

Comment: А в коде для этого ничего делать не нужно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к серверу из интернета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523111/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)