# Tomcat+домен, размещение сайта в седи интернет

Tags: java, tomcat, domain

У меня есть веб-сайт написанный с помощью Java и поднят на Tomcat, я новичок в этом деле.
Сайт у меня работает на localhost, не могу понять, как разместить его для всеобщего доступа.
К примеру, я должен купить(зарегистрировать) доменное имя, а что дальше...

Comment: Купите домен, купите у к-л хостера сервак (VPS/VDS). Установите на этот сервер весь нужный софт (java, tomcat). Пропишите у регистратора домена IP сервера в параметрах домена. Запустите ваше приложение на сервере через Tomcat.

Comment: [Заливаем проект на бесплатный хостинг](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPvxfx8g8kQ&list=PLYjyDlouoSEcCDmi4V-YslQZ4JEBQqUpE&index=54)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к серверу из интернета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523111/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)