# Nginx настройка вне локальной сети

Tags: nginx

Всем привет,такой вопрос:
У менять через Docker работает сервис,на который я могу зайти в локальной сети по my_local_ip:8080, но как настроить Nginx чтобы я мог зайти через свой внешний IP,вне локальной сети ,на него

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к серверу из интернета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523111/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: увы. но нужного ответа по вашей ссылке нет

Comment: Откуда берётся «внешний ip»? Я на 99% уверен что настраивать надо роутер. Собственно это написано в первом ответе по ссылке. Если он вам не подходит, то у вас какая-то очень уникальная схема сети и нужны подробности

Comment: Внешний ip куплен у провайдера,переадресация нужных портов настроена

Answer (score 1):

Нужно настроить маршрутизатор и опубликовать нужный порт контейнера:

1. Используя docker-compose.yml и директиву [ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)
2. или опцию [-p](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) docker клиента.