# Как создать хостинг из своего ПК?

Tags: веб-программирование, хостинг, веб-сайт

Хотелось бы создать хостинг `(Не локальный)` из своего пк, но не знаю как.
Буду рад вашей помощи.

Comment: Получить у провайдера статический IP, настроить роутер для передачи данных на ваш ПК, если нужно, зарегистрировать домен и изменить его DNS у регистратора.

Comment: А в чем преимущество статического IP над динамическим?

Comment: Преимуществ нет. Статический не меняется, динамический меняется.

Comment: @Greyfroot В том, что Ваш сайт (или что будете размещать там) будет работать) Динамический IP Вы никак к DNS не привяжете, только если каждую смену ручками будете менять. Собственно, если что-то другое, что не требует DNS, то так же требуется к IP подключаться, а IP каждый раз меняется – как будете ситуацию решать?)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar DDNS, no-ip

Comment: Думаю для начала нужно узнать про 'не' с глаголами

Comment: Ваш провайдер, так же, может не предоставлять даже публичного динамического IP(его можно в настройках роутера наковырять). Вы можете жить внутри сети провайдера с внутренними адресами. Так что вам нужен IP, по которому все пользователи сети интернет смогут достучаться до вас. Отложите пока эту затею и потратьте час другой почитав, как устроено общение ПК в сети, как организованы сети, про домены 1-2-3 уровня и организацию взаимодействия с ними и внутри. Очень полезно будет. На много не заданных вопросов найдете ответы )

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к серверу из интернета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523111/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

1. поставить гипервизор(для начала VirtualBox, он человекопонятный дальше некуда. но серьёзные дяди юзают всякие докеры с куберами, ВМварь и прочее)
2. в VM развернуть контейнер с привычной ОС, дав ему доступ в сеть(в VB в свойствах машины ~пара галочек)
3. в контейнере поднять LAMP сервер. для винды например OpenServer хорош
4. в лампе включить доступ к хостам из-вне(в OS буквально одна галочка в настройках, формально с этого момента LAMP растопырит свои порты на всю доступную сеть и каждый второй вася пупкин сможет постучаться из неё брутфорсом, во всё что плохо фильтруется)
5. получить IP(выдается автоматически при подключении к инэту. в идеале конечно нужен публично статический, но для эксперимента любой сойдет. глянуть свой IP можно в свойствах подключения либо на спец ресурсах вроде 2ip иль как он там называется...)

p.s. статический выдается раз и "навсегда", динамический может меняться(и будет меняться) при почти каждом подключении. статические за бесплатно почти не раздаются наверное лет эдак 20(мелкие провайдеры конечно могут и выдавать, но это если повезёт и только до тех пор пока у провайдера пул свободных IP не начнет иссякать)

6. прицепить к своему ip домен 2го\3го уровня(название вбиваемое в адресную строку браузера). на обновление домена(считай применение настроек) уходит ~3е суток. в случае с динамическим ip как только отключишься от сети и подключишься обратно, с высокой долей вероятности провайдер даст уже другой ip. если это произошло - цеплять домен надо заново(ждать еще 3е суток). но цеплять домен конечно не обязательно, можно заходить просто вбив ip нужного сервака в адресную строку, для того чтоб убедиться в успешности эксперимента этого более чем достаточно.
7. поставить "шарилку" ресурсов