# как сделать FullStack приложение доступным в интернете по ссылке

Tags: сервер, express, веб-сервер, backend

помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Есть небольшое FullStack приложение, реализовано клиент серверное взаимодействие. С использованием React/Redux/express/SQLite

Если с выгрузкой фронтенда понятно, просто выгружаешь на GitHubPages и можно заходить по ссылке все работает.

То как мне сделать тоже самое с FullStack приложением? Можно как то локально на ПК сделать свой сервер? Чтобы я фронтенд выгрузил на GitHubPages, а зашедший пользователь мог отправлять запросы на сервер, который находиться на моем ПК например. Грубо говоря сайт работает, только когда включен ПК. Или куда еще можно загрузить эту папку 'server' чтобы работало все?

Я вообще не представляю как это должно работать, куда это все загружается, и так далее.
Помогите разобраться с этим, в инете находил только, где люди локально на ПК делают FullStack приложение, если пользователь с другого ПК зайдет на сайт, то у него не будет работать.

Дайте пожалуйста совет, литературу, статью или видео.

Answer (score 1):

1. github pages можно платно апать(без бэк-рантайма только бесплатная версия)
2. на том же git загляните в codespace и попробуйте там создать новый "спейс", сам еще его не расщупал, но выглядит как халявный 4х ядерный vps\хост
3. есть куча бесплатных и условно-бесплатных как хостов так и vps
4. как сделать хост из своего ПК относительно подробно расписывал тут: [Как создать хостинг из своего ПК?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1465384/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%9f%d0%9a/1465425#1465425)

// ну как подробно... по сути названия действий перечислил, чтоб было ясно что именно гуглить :3