# Найти глобальный (белый) IP для Raspberry Pi Pico W

Tags: micropython

Недавно мне купили Raspberry Pi Pico W, поэтому я начал создавать сайт. Всё готово, но осталось найти способ получить белый IP для переадресации портов. Как можно узнать этот IP?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к серверу из интернета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523111/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Копался я долго, но я нашёл способ. Для этого надо было сделать этот код:

```py
import network, time
ssid = 'None' # Название вашей сети
password = 'None' # Пароль вашей сети
wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect(ssid, password)
max_wait = 10
while max_wait > 0:
    if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
        break
    max_wait -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
if wlan.status() != 3:
    raise RuntimeError('Не удалось подключиться.')
else:
    status = wlan.ifconfig()
    print( 'Локальный IP = ' + status[0])

import urequests
response = urequests.get('https://api64.ipify.org')
data = response.text
print("Глобальный IP = " + data)
```

Если я кому-то помог, то буду рад.

Comment: Но это не даст вам возможности пробросить порты

Answer (score 0):

Для переадресации нужно использовать сервисы TURN(обычно платный) или STUN(только UDP). Знание белого IP4 не даст возможности подключиться к серверу.

Есть ещё пара сервисов в интернете для пробросов HTTP.